# System.Threading multiple users

Tags: .net

I have been asked to add a splash page to an old ASP website written in VB.Net

This is an external facing website that is accessed by thousands of people per day.

I have added the following methods for the on click events of the link buttons:

```
    Protected Sub linkWelsh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles linkWelsh.Click
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hi-IN")
    Response.Redirect("~/Content/mainPageOne.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub linkEnglish_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles linkEnglish.Click
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB")
    Response.Redirect("~/Content/mainPageOne.aspx")
    End Sub
```

Upon testing this works fine, and allows me to browse beyond `mainPageOne` with the language consistent.

However, my question is...

If I have 100 users simultaneously, and one of them clicks the welsh link on the splash page, will this UI Culture change made to the current thread only relate to them, i.e. does each new user get a thread and therefore by changing the current thread mean it is only going to affect them.

Or is there the potential for this thread change to affect someone other than themselves.

Apologies if this is a stupid question however I am not familiar with the `System.Threading` class when dealing with multiple users.

Comment: Think of your App as stateless, because it is. You'll have to set the language in each request. Based on a cookie or Session[] setting.